# copy input with .each() to multiple divs

Tags: jquery, each, keyup

i want to copy the input from a user to multiple div's.
I tried to use .each() because i want to apply it to every div that follows.
I wrote this code so far, but it's only working for the first div.

```
<input type="text" name="someText" id="someText">



$("#someText").keyup(function() {
    var x = $("#someText").val();
    $("#copy").each(function () {
        $(this).html(x);
    });
});


<div id="copy"></div>
<div id="copy"></div>
```

Best Regards,

Felix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IDs have to be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2):

> `id = name [CS`]
>       This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

Most browsers will return the first element of a document with a given ID, though the behaviour is unspecified.

Use classes instead if you want to select multiple elements:

HTML:

```
<div class="copy"></div>
<div class="copy"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#someText").keyup(function() {
    $(".copy").text(this.value);
});
```

Some other points:

- You don't have to use `.each`, setter methods are normally always applied to all elements of the set.
- Inside the event handler, `this` refers to the element the handler is bound to. You don't have to use the selector again.
- If you already have a reference to a DOM element, it is often simpler to just access one of its properties directly instead of going through jQuery.

Comment: it works now! i also considered your other points. you were a great help:) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that JQuery only gets the first instance when you use an ID selector.

If you assign a class instead it should work.

Personally I would go for this...

```
<input type="text" name="someText" id="someText">

$("#someText").keyup(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $(".copy").html(x);
});

<div class="copy"></div>
<div class="copy"></div>
```

Or you could use `name=copy` and selector like so...

```
$("[name=copy]").html(x);
```

Though depending on how your data works it might be best not to have duplicate "name" attribute values

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't think this would fail, but you should nevertheless use class instead of ids here.

```
<div class="copy"></div>
<div class="copy"></div>
```

Then you can add the value from the input like this:

```
$("#someText").keyup(function() { $('.copy').text($(this).val()); });
```

Note that I changed your example to use the text function instead of the .html function. Because you bind to the keyup event, chances are that *if* the user inputs HTML, the HTML you insert before the tag is finished would be broken. If you want to accept HTML you should bind to the blur event instead:

```
$("#someText").blur(function() { $('.copy').html($(this).val()); });
```

Answer (score 2):

use class instead of ID. Problem solved :-)

```
<input type="text" name="someText" id="someText">

<script>

    $("#someText").keyup(function() {
        var x = $("#someText").val();
        $(".copy").each(function () {
            $(this).html(x);
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="copy"></div>
<div class="copy"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function getID(obj) {   
   //alert(obj);
   //for text 1 
   $("#t1").val(obj);
}
</script>
```

**Html**

```
<td onClick="getID('${vusers.id}');" id="vid">
   Click on this text
</td>

<input type="text" size=10 id="t1" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're solution is.  I don't think this is answering the question.  Can you provide a working example of this (like in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))